# page blank when set cookie in symfony

Tags: symfony, cookies, symfony-2.8

I am facing issue to set cookie in symfony, I am beginners in symfony,

I set cookie on form POST by

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;


$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie("city", $city));
$response->send();
```

It's working fine but page get blank on form POST.

Also its set, I check using

```
 if ($cookies->has('city')) {
             $city = $cookies->get('city');
      }
```

Seems issue with $response->send(); When i comment its work but cookie not set.

is it right way to set cookie in symfony?

i am issue php 7.0.17, fpm apache

please help to fix this issue,

Comment: can you try `return $response->send();` or  `return $response;` instead of `$response->send();`

Comment: Not work :(  here is link http://lab.instructiveride.com/en/ride/ where i face issue on search by city. i want to keep user search in cookie, Normal reload page after search

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put the whole object city in your cookie you should send only the id. THe object can change between the time you put it in the cookie and the time the value is read.

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie("city", $city->getId()));
$response->send();
```

On my project I use it this way without any problem

```
$response = $this->render(
    'your/twig.html.twig',[
        'param'  => $param,
    ]
);
$response->headers->setCookie(
   new Cookie(
       'name',
        $value, //value
        0,     //Expire
        '/',   //path
        null,  //domain
        false, //Secure
        false  //httponly
        )
    );

return $response;
```